# Why give gifts AFTER the cup of parting?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring, galadriel

In *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Galadriel says:

> ‘We  have  drunk  the  cup  of  parting,’  she  said,  ‘and  the shadows  fall  between  us.  But  before  you  go,  I  have  brought in  my  ship  gifts  which  the  Lord  and  Lady  of  the  Galadhrim now  offer  you  in  memory  of  Lothlorien.’

It seems to me this is out of order. Why not give gifts and *then* drink the cup of parting, before the shadows grow between them?

Comment: Not all customs make sense to people not raised in them.

Comment: Barring an infodump from Tolkien about Elvish etiquette, any answer would be opinion-based.

Comment: @user888379 - We have entire books of info-dumps from Tolkien

Comment: @Valorum indeed. Which is my I qualified my categorization of possible answers :)

Comment: @user888379 - barring an infodump from Tolkien, "we don't know" would be a perfectly acceptable answer

Comment: From a practical standpoint: you give *parting* gifts when you're actually parting, and the Cup of Parting indicates that you're parting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### This is a reference to Beowulf

Let's look at the preceding lines to your quote, which describe the actual drinking of the cup.

> Now Galadriel rose from the grass, and taking a cup from one of her maidens **she filled it with white mead and gave it to Celeborn.**
>
> ‘Now it is time to drink the cup of farewell,’ she said. ‘Drink, Lord of the Galadhrim! And let not your heart be sad, though night must follow noon, and already our evening draweth nigh.’
>
> **Then she brought the cup to each of the Company,** and bade them drink and farewell.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book II Chapter 8 - "Farewell to Lórien"</sub>

According to Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull, this passage is a reference to a passage in *Beowulf*.

> Then she brought the cup to each of the Company - In this Galadriel follows ancient customs as portrayed in *Beowulf*.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion*</sub>

In *Beowulf* (lines 612-641), Wealhtheow, Queen of the Danes, offers a cup of mead first to her husband Hrothgar, and then to everyone else in the hall.

Here is the passage from *Beowulf* in Tolkien's own translation:

> **Wealhtheow went forth, Hrothgar’s queen,** mindful of courtesy; with gold adorned she greeted the men in the hall, and then **the cup she offered, noble lady, first to the guardian of the East Danes’ realm,** and wished him joy at the ale-quaffing and his lieges’ love. He, king victorious, in delight partook of feast and flowing bowl. **Then the lady of the Helmings went to and fro to every part of that host, to tried men and young proffering the jewelled vessels,** until in due time it chanced that she, ring-laden queen of courteous heart, to Beowulf bore the cup of mead, and hailed the Geatish knight, and gave thanks to God in words of wisdom that her desire was granted to her that she might trust in any man for comfort in their miseries. That cup he then received, grim warrior at Wealhtheow’s hand, and thereupon, his heart being kindled with desire of battle, fair words he said. Thus Beowulf, son of Ecgtheow, spake: ‘This did I purpose when I went up upon the sea and sat me in my sea-boat amid my company of knights, that I wholly would accomplish the desire of your people or would fall among the slain fast in the clutches of the foe. A deed of knightly valour I shall achieve, or else in this mead-hall await my latest day!’ These words well pleased that lady, the proud utterance of the Geat; with gold adorned she went, fair queen of the people, to her seat beside her lord.
> <sub>*Beowulf: A Translation and Commentary* - lines 498-521</sub>

Note that this cup is not a stirrup-cup given right as everyone is setting out (like we see in Book VI, Chapter 6 "Many Partings": "Now the guests were ready, and they drank the stirrup-cup, and with great praise and friendship they departed").

In both the Wealhtheow scene in *Beowulf* and the Galadriel scene here in *The Lord of the Rings*, additional things happen between the passing around of the mead cup and the departure. After Wealhtheow sits down, it is said that feast resumes ("Then again as before were valiant words spoken within the hall, the host was in joyful hour, there was clamour of folk triumphant"). And after the Fellowship drinks, Galadriel sits them all down and hands out gifts. ("But when they had drunk she commanded them to sit again on the grass, and chairs were set for her and for Celeborn.")

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't really count talking as an additional thing happening after passing the cup, unless it was a ritual speech of some sort. What else does she do other than sit back down? Galadriel specifically gave gifts, some of which were quite valuable.

Comment: @MichaelFoster - Talking (and gift-giving) is very much a 'thing that happens afterwards'. A traditional stirrup cup is proffered and the taker drinks, passes it back, wipes their lips and then rides away. No additional words (apart from a hearty thanks, and *God be with you*) are normally said

Comment: @MichaelFoster - In Beowulf after the cup gets passed around (and after quote I gave above ends), the feast resumes as it was prior to the cup. *Then again as before were valiant words spoken within the hall, the host was in joyful hour, there was clamour of folk triumphant.*

Comment: [For a more modern Beowulf translation.](https://i.imgur.com/leFKeGP.png) (*Beowulf: A New Translation* by Maria Dahvana Headley)